# how to show the save button at the last step. 5 steps are there save button will show the last step

Tags: javascript, jquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDRBb.png)

```
<input id="btnPrevious" onclick="DisplayPreviousDiv();" type="button" value="Previous" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs hidden1" />

<input id="btnNext" onclick="DisplayNextDiv();" type="button" value="Next" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" />


<asp:Button ID="btnafsave" runat="server" Text="Save" class="btn btn-success btn-xs savebtn" OnClick="btnafsave_Click" />[enter image description here][1]

<asp:Button ID="btnafrefresh" runat="server" Text="Refresh" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" />

<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" OnClick="btnafsave_Click" CommandName="Update" />
```

i am trying to hide my save button and it will show at last step. it is in side the div tag.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. In order to help you please provide your code(what you try so far).

Comment: you can try making a variable then make it as your count. then every next step increment your step

Comment: use one buttom at last of every div and appy click event on that  for show hide other   try and provide sample  code you try after that able to help you